# How to get window.checkoutConfig data via REST API?

Tags: magento2, checkout, rest-api, webapi

I am building a custom frontend for Magento 2 Checkout. Sometimes the checkout uses `window.checkoutConfig`in the built-in frontend. My frontend uses the REST API provided by Magento 2, but how can I access data that is normally set on window.checkoutConfig? Am I missing some endpoint?